# Invoke-Webrequest asp login form

Tags: forms, powershell, asp-classic

I'm trying to grab my some details from my router, specifically my wan ip. I had this working yesterday, then I copied this block to a larger script and purged old source. Now its not working and its driving me crazy.

```
$RtrMainPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.0.1'

$RtrLoginForm = $RtrMainPage.Forms
$RtrLoginForm.Fields["login_name"] = "admin"
$RtrLoginForm.Fields["login_pass"] = "password"

$LoginResp = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.0.1/login.cgi' -Method POST -Body $RtrLoginForm -SessionVariable RtrSes #-ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$RtrIPReq = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://192.168.0.1/st_device.asp' -WebSession $RtrSes 

$RtrWANIp = $RtrIPReq.Forms[0].Fields.wan_current_ipaddr.split('/')[0]
```

Here is the response header

> 'HTTP/1.0 200 Ok Pragma: no-cache
>   Connection: close Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: text/html
>   Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2013 20:45:35 GMT Expires: 0 Server: httpd
>
> function redirect(){   document.location.href =
>   '';}    redirect();

Here are the input fields

```
innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT id=html_response_page type=hidden value=login.asp name=html_response_page>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
id        : html_response_page
type      : hidden
value     : login.asp
name      : html_response_page

innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT id=login_name type=hidden name=login_name>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
id        : login_name
type      : hidden
name      : login_name

innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT id=login_pass type=hidden name=login_pass>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
id        : login_pass
type      : hidden
name      : login_pass

innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT id=graph_id type=hidden value=1c540 name=graph_id>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
id        : graph_id
type      : hidden
value     : 1c540
name      : graph_id

innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT id=alert_id type=hidden value=0 name=alert_id>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
id        : alert_id
type      : hidden
value     : 0
name      : alert_id

innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT tabIndex=120 onfocus=select(); id=log_pass type=password value="" name=log_pass>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
tabIndex  : 120
onfocus   : select();
id        : log_pass
type      : password
value     : 
name      : log_pass

innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT onfocus=select(); id=graph_code maxLength=8 type=password value="" name=graph_code>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
onfocus   : select();
id        : graph_code
maxLength : 8
type      : password
value     : 
name      : graph_code

innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT onclick="window.location.reload( true );" id=Refresh class=button_submit_padleft style="WIDTH: 120px" 
            type=button name=Refresh>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
onclick   : window.location.reload( true );
id        : Refresh
class     : button_submit_padleft
style     : WIDTH: 120px
type      : button
name      : Refresh

innerHTML : 
innerText : 
outerHTML : <INPUT id=login class=button_submit_padleft style="WIDTH: 120px" type=submit name=login>
outerText : 
tagName   : INPUT
id        : login
class     : button_submit_padleft
style     : WIDTH: 120px
type      : submit
name      : login
```

I thought maybe i had dropped a field like

```
$RtrLoginForm.Fields["login"] = "submit"
```

But that didn't work.

Anyway my eyes hurt and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Shot in the dark here: are you now running this script on Server Core, rather than a server with a GUI or a client OS?

Comment: running on win7 right now. ps ver Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      8      0      129

Comment: Another question, does it work when run interactively but fail when run as a scheduled task, or does it fail all the time? If you could clarify which lines are "working" and where the problem comes, that would be helpful.

Comment: running from powergui...interactively. Its failing creating $RtrWANIp with null-valued expression. Because I'm not getting logged in and not able to hit /st_device.asp

Comment: The form is referring to `login.asp` but your code is `POST`ing to `login.cgi`.

Comment: if i post to login.asp i get underlying connection closed